# Getting query results from 3 dbs when result only matches parameters of 1 db

Tags: mysql, union, multiple-databases

Say I have 3 companies that all have customers.  I want to write a code that searches all 3 companies for customers that have been terminated and laid off, then returns all the companies that that person is a customer with, regardless of that customers status with those companies.

The best code I have is:

```
SELECT
x.name,
x.social,
  CASE
  when (SUM(x.company) = 1) then ('A')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 2) then ('B')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 4) then ('C')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 3) then ('A + B')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 5) then ('A + C')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 6) then ('B + C')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 7) then ('X')
  else NULL end AS company

FROM
(SELECT 
a.name as name, 
a.socsec, 
("1") AS company
FROM
 a
WHERE
  (a.status = 'Active') AND 
  ((a.trans IN ('Payroll','HR')) AND 
  (a.result IN ('Terminated','LaidOff')) 
GROUP BY
  a.socsec

UNION

SELECT 
b.name as name, 
b.socsec, 
("2") AS company
FROM
 b
WHERE
  (b.status = 'Active') AND 
  ((b.trans IN ('Payroll','HR')) AND 
  (b.result IN ('Terminated','LaidOff')) 
GROUP BY
  b.socsec

UNION

SELECT 
c.name as name, 
c.socsec, 
("4") AS company
FROM
 c
WHERE
  (c.status = 'Active') AND 
  ((c.trans IN ('Payroll','HR')) AND 
  (c.result IN ('Terminated','LaidOff'))
GROUP BY
  c.socsec) idx

GROUP BY
 x.socsec
ORDER BY
 company
```

This code only returns customer accounts that meet the terminated filters, so if I have a customer with a terminated code in company A but a normal account in B, it only returns that she has an account with A.
Id like it to return 'A+B' for that customer, so as long as any one of a customers accounts meets the filters it should return all companies that customer has an account with.

The best solution I could think of was UNIONing all the accounts between all 3 companies then applying the filters in an OR statement outside of the UNION but that takes so long to run it freezes and Im not even sure that would work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking this could work but it takes so long it freezes, would this be a working solution that my system just cant handle?

```
SELECT
x.name,
x.social,
 CASE
  when (SUM(x.company) = 1) then ('A')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 2) then ('B')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 4) then ('C')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 3) then ('A + B')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 5) then ('A + C')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 6) then ('B + C')
  when (SUM(x.company) = 7) then ('X')
  else NULL end AS co

FROM
(
  SELECT 
   a.name, 
   a.social, 
   ("1") AS company
   FROM a

UNION

  SELECT 
   b.name, 
   b.social, 
   ("2") AS company
   FROM b

UNION

  SELECT 
   c.name, 
   c.social, 
   ("4") AS company
   FROM c
) idx

LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.social = x.social
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.socsec = x.socsec
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.socsec = x.socsec

WHERE
((a.status = 'Active') AND 
(a.balance > 0.00) AND 
(a.trans IN ('Payroll','HR')) AND 
(a.result IN ('Terminated','LaidOff')))
OR
((b.status = 'Active') AND 
(b.balance > 0.00) AND 
(b.trans IN ('Payroll','HR')) AND 
(b.result IN ('Terminated','LaidOff')))
OR
((c.status = 'Active') AND 
(c.balance > 0.00) AND 
(c.trans IN ('Payroll','HR')) AND 
(c.result IN ('Terminated','LaidOff')))

GROUP BY x.social
ORDER BY co
```